Can't post in curl multiple data
I'm sending some data through xml code, problem is that in xml I want to send multiple <GOODS></GOODS> with some data in it (It depends on product items quantity) have no idea what to do.
$number_array = $_POST['numbers'];
$name_array = $_POST['name'];
$quantity_array = $_POST['quantity'];
$price_array = $_POST['totprice'];

$output1 = ''.implode(' ',  $number_array).' ';
echo $output1;

$output2 = ''.implode(' ',  $name_array).' ';
echo $output2;

$output3 = ''.implode(' ',  $quantity_array).' ';
echo $output3;

$output4 = ''.implode(' ',  $price_array).' ';
echo $output4;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {

$name = ($name_array[$i]);
$number = ($number_array[$i]);
$quantity = ($quantity_array[$i]);
$price = ($price_array[$i]);

}


$xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<save_waybill xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<su>username</su>
<sp>password</sp>
<waybill>
<WAYBILL>
<SUB_WAYBILLS></SUB_WAYBILLS>

<GOODS_LIST>

I need this are to be same quantity as I submit products in above code (array)
<GOODS>
<ID>0</ID>
<W_NAME>Name1</W_NAME>
<UNIT_ID>1</UNIT_ID>
<UNIT_TXT></UNIT_TXT>
<QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
<PRICE>100</PRICE>
<STATUS>1</STATUS>
<AMOUNT>2</AMOUNT>
<BAR_CODE>123</BAR_CODE>
<A_ID>0</A_ID>
<VAT_TYPE>0</VAT_TYPE>
</GOODS>


Use the DOMDocument class to create XML, rather than concatenating strings.

This seems to be a SOAP API, here is ext/soap for this.
